# How to get GridView style in Exported Excel

Tags: winforms, devexpress, export-to-excel, xtragrid

I have migrated my application to Dev Express 15.2.After migration data is not exporting in GridView style.Like alternate row color,Font ..etc.Do we have any option to export the data same as like in grid.

**Designer:**

```
  this.gridView1.Appearance.EvenRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;
        this.gridView1.Appearance.EvenRow.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.gridView1.Appearance.GroupPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(74)))), ((int)(((byte)(74)))), ((int)(((byte)(74)))));
        this.gridView1.Appearance.GroupPanel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.gridView1.Appearance.GroupPanel.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.gridView1.Appearance.GroupPanel.Options.UseFont = true;
        this.gridView1.Appearance.HeaderPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(194)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.gridView1.Appearance.HeaderPanel.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.gridView1.AppearancePrint.EvenRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;
        this.gridView1.AppearancePrint.EvenRow.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.gridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn[] {
        this.gridColumn1,
        this.gridColumn2,
        this.gridColumn3,
        this.gridColumn4,
        this.gridColumn5});
        this.gridView1.GridControl = this.gridControl1;
        this.gridView1.GroupSummary.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridSummaryItem[] {
        new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridGroupSummaryItem(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Count, "OrderID", null, "")});
        this.gridView1.Name = "gridView1";
        this.gridView1.OptionsView.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
```

**Code in cs file**

```
    if(ext == "xlsx")
        {
            XlsxExportOptionsEx options = new XlsxExportOptionsEx();
            options.ShowGridLines = false;
            options.AllowSortingAndFiltering = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
            options.ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.WYSIWYG;
            exportView.ExportToXlsx(filename, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting following properties issue is solved.

```
            ((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)gridControl1.MainView).OptionsPrint.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
            ((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)gridControl1.MainView).OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = false;
```